# COUNT(id) or MAX(id) - which is faster?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have a web server on which I've implemented my own messaging system.
I am at a phase where I need to create an API that checks if the user has new messages.

My DB table is simple:

```
ID - Auto Increment, Primary Key (Bigint)
Sender - Varchar (32) // Foreign Key to UserID hash from Users DB Table
Recipient - Varchar (32) // Foreign Key to UserID hash from Users DB Table
Message - Varchar (256) //UTF8 BIN
```

I am considering making an API that will estimate if there are new messages for a given user. I am thinking of using one of these methods:

**A)** Select `count(ID)` of messages where sender or recipient is me.
(if this number > previous number, I have a new message)

**B)** Select `max(ID)` of messages where sender or recipient is me.
(if max(ID) > than previous number, I have a new message)

My question is:  Can I calculate somehow what method will consume fewer server resources? Or is there some article? Maybe another method I didn't mention?

Comment: I think you would be better off by adding a timestamp column and checking against that value to see if there are newer records.

Comment: Either querying a timestamp or the ID, use `MAX()` on that column, and make sure it's indexed with `(user_id, timestamp)`.

Comment: @Dharman i was thinking of it. But it costs extra DB space, also i am not sure if it will be faster than one of my methods. I am storing the simple number (of current messages)  in usernames table

Comment: Calculate? No idea. But you can _measure_ it. Fire off a few thousands of each query and watch machine metrics (cpu%, mem%, load average, etc.)

Comment: While there is a good answer to this question below, I suspect you might be optimizing on something that turns out not to be important. And unless you anticipate having literally millions of messages, I wouldn't worry about disk space, especially because the timestamp is small compared to your other fields. If you add timestamps, your table will be about 5MB larger for each million messages. That's really nothing.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see the indexes and other details.

Comment: When the table gets really big, those hashes will kill performance due to the I/O caused by the randomness of hashes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In MySQL InnoDB, `SELECT COUNT(id) WHERE secondary_index = ?` is an expensive operation and when the user has a lot of messages, this query might take a long time. Even when using an index, the engine still needs to count all matching records. The performance will degrade with growing total message count.

On the other hand, `SELECT MAX(id) WHERE secondary_index = ?` can deliver the highest id in that index in almost constant time by doing a simple drilldown in the B-Tree structure of the index.

*If you want to understand why, consider looking up how the [B+Tree](http://www.unofficialmysqlguide.com/btrees.html) data structure works, which is used by InnoDB to structure the rows of your tables and indexes.*

I suggest you go with `SELECT MAX(id)`, if the requirement is only to check if there are *new* messages (and not the count of them).

Also, if you rely on the message count you might open a gap for race conditions. What if the user deletes a message and receives a new one between two polling intervals?

Comment: "SELECT MAX(id) will always use the primary index" - yeah, except for the cases when there's a `where` on an unindexed field.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i forgot to mention in my main post, sender and recipient are foreign keys to user-hash (ID) - primary key in users table. So it will be indexed always.

Comment: @Kaii "Also, if you rely on the message count you might open a gap for race conditions. What if the user deletes a message and receives a new one between two polling intervals?"   if the user deletes the message it just become hidden for security reasons, it will have a value hidden:true. but the count will not change

Comment: @Kaii thanks , i will accept your answer as a solution, made a cycle of 2000 selects of both alternatives. Your suggested method is ~24% faster in the table of 7020 records.

Comment: @FeHora add a few million more records to see more impressive results ;-)

Comment: @Kaii i cannot add records to the live system :) The time will tell how fast it is. The people are chatting, so the records growing pretty fast. BTW message text is encrypted and not human-readable, only sender/recipient can read. Just to ensure i am not a stalker :)

Comment: If there's an index on `a`, then `SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl WHERE a=constant` uses a so-called *loose index scan*. Those are almost miraculously fast.  `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE a=constant` does a *tight index scan,* which is not as fast.

Comment: @FeHora i strongly suggest to setup some sort of test environment, a database with generated records for you to play with.

Answer (score 4):

To have the information that someone has new messages - do exactly that. Update the field in `users` table (I'm assuming that's the name) when a new message is recorded in the system. You have the recipient's ID, that's all you need. You can create an `after insert` trigger (assumption: there's `users2messages` table) that updates users table with a boolean flag indicating there's a message.

This approach is by far faster than counting indexes, be the index primary or secondary. When the user performs an action, you can update the `users` table with `has_messages = 0`, when a new message arrives - you update the table with `has_messages = 1`. It's simple, it works, it scales and using triggers to maintain it makes it easy and seamless. 
I'm sure there will be  nay-sayers who don't like triggers, you can do it manually at the point of associating a user with a new message.

Comment: triggers aside, looking up a row using the PK and also *reading it* to check the boolean is still more expensive than executing a single loose index scan. It gets worse when you also add a WHERE clause to check the boolean flag because of the low cardinality even if you index that field. Sorry to tell you you that, but you have a misunderstanding there.

Comment: @Mjh i know about that.. but it's definitely more expensive than my suggested methods, because it contains (at least) 1x update + 1x select

Comment: @Kaii `SELECT has_messages FROM users WHERE id = 1;` is the fastest query there is. It's an `eq_ref` which is infinitely faster than counting a number of records in the table. The boolean field is not in the `WHERE` clause, the primary key is. Please, assume better next time. In regards to updating the table: the update is fast as well, it handles a single row located using the primary key. If the field is already containing the value that you're updating to, no actual disk I/O occurs and there's a minimal performance penalty. Much less than counting the records. You can measure.

Comment: Well ... Taking into account that we're talking about _[1 trigger including 1 lookup and 1 update to set the flag + 1 lookup and 1 update to unset the flag]_ *vs* _[1 loose index scan]_, i think it's obvious what's more overhead. But sure, you can measure. ;-) You are right that `eq_ref` is the fastest kind of lookup, but doing it four times including two updates just doesn't compare to a single, very simple operation.

Comment: @Kaii "loose" index scan means you have to go through the dataset (which can be in RAM but doesn't have to be) every time you want the data, or you perform a simple lookup and a simple operation that takes less CPU time and incurs less I/O wait. Bottom line being that you obtain the data faster every time you need it (are there messages or not) opposed to counting *every single record* every time you want a yes/no. For some reason, you can't seem to grasp that simple optimization step. I can't explain it easier, I doubt you're even reading.

Comment: @mhj MAX(id) on an indexed field is almost as fast as eq_ref lookup. No COUNTING. Single operation vs 5 operations. Believe what you want. Learn to unterstand B+Tree before misdirecting people.

Comment: @mhj for your better understanding: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/minmax-optimization/

Comment: @Kaii had you read and understood every single word I wrote, we wouldn't be having this very awkward exchange. Let me show by example: `It gets worse when you also add a WHERE clause to check the boolean flag`. Query I spoke of had no `WHERE boolean_field = 1/0;`. You'd know that had you read it. `there is no counting involved` - that means the computer.. guesses using telepathy since there's no counting involved. When a CPU performs a count, that doesn't mean it executes SQL's `COUNT(*)`, it means it iterates through a set that satisfies given conditions. There's too big of a language barrier

Comment: MAX() is not COUNT() and works totally different. But hey, just continue to ignore this fact and carry on.

Comment: Temporarily locked until the comments can calm down. Make your point and leave it at that. Comments are not for extended debate, nor insults.

Comment: @Kali -- how are you hanging onto the old `id` for checking against the new `MAX(id)`?

Comment: BTW, `MAX(id)` was optimized in MySQL long before "loose index scan" was added.  I suspect "loose index scan" is not relevant to this discussion.  And, yes, finding `MAX(id)` is a simple BTree drill-down; it is just doing it the 'end' instead of the 'start'.

Comment: @RickJames actually a query would look like `SELECT MAX(id) FROM messages WHERE user_id = ?` so the query is not using the PK but rather a secondary `INDEX(user_id)`, which makes no difference for the performance in this case. So there is no old/new ID issue. And you are right, MAX(id) is not using a real loose index scan here. Didn't know how do describe it better. "b-tree drilldown" sounds good. Maybe that's the reason for the huge miscommunication here.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to know the number of new messages then using
`Select count(*) from Messages where user_id in (sender, recipient) and id > last_seen_id` would be your best option.

I'm a fan of using `exists` where possible, so to determine IF there are new messages, my query would be `Select exists(Select 1 from Messages where user_id in (sender, recipient) and id > last_seen_id)`. The benefit of exists is that as soon as it finds 1 record it returns `true`.

Edit: To avoid any confusion in reading this answer, both of those queries would also include a check for `other_user_id in (sender, recipient)` in order to only return the messages between 2 specific users.

Comment: And that implies a 3-column composite index.

Answer (score -2):

@FeHora You talk about not using keys to save db space. The table designs wastes more db space.

```
ID - Auto Increment, Primary Key (Bigint)
```

Is `bigint` really necessary? Let us assume, the a message is send every second. The a `int unsigned` is enough for 126 years. And if you have really so much messages, a key is mandatory.

```
Sender - Varchar (32) // Foreign Key to UserID hash from Users DB Table
Recipient - Varchar (32) // Foreign Key to UserID hash from Users DB Table
```

Why not using the `UserID` (usually an `int unsigned`).

Then I would add a seen flags. Btw, you can add for all filed the attribute `not null`.

```
seen tinyint not NULL.
```

Last not least I recomment the variant of @Mjh : Define a flag `has_messages`, or `new_messages`, or both in the user record. Usually, the user record is loaded so it is NOT an additional database query.

Comment: This messaging system is for a government-ish organization, 90% of messages are sent to users from systems (like temperature in room is above 30C ..etc etc).. It can generate millions of messages per hour, that's why i need to optimize every microsecond of server time. I cannot use UserID key because of reverse engineering + GDPR (EU thing). Long story short - i need to have everything encrypted and fast. every additional data field can cause a lot of extra unwanted database storage space.

Comment: @FeHora if what you wrote is true, then the accepted answer is exactly what you want to avoid. Million records per hour is only 278 inserts per second. Even old mechanical drivers were able to pull of ~400 IOPS, current SSDs are starting at 5k IOPS and getting 250k IOPS drive is not expensive any more. If it's a government asset, I take it you won't run it on a Raspberry Pi but a server with sufficient RAM and storage (128GB of RAM, a few TB of SSD). That just means that your microoptimizations aren't worth it. However, suggesting a `varchar(32)` key for a foreign key is.. just bad.

Comment: why @Mjh ? the change (if have new mail) is written only once (in end-user android app cookies), so it's not torturing the database system/performance. Only one select until the user opening new messages tab. The app has mobile notifications and works only in local area (intranet app). So the accepted answer is exactly that costs minimal server resources. Now i have 800+ users logged in and DB server/web server load is ~2%  . I am using failover , so the data must be shipped to backup server also, in real time. 2% is really not too much.

Comment: @FeHora because it's not the fastest solution. Your load will remain low, but the conclusion that the chosen method if the best because server load is low is false conclusion. Currently, you're unaware if you're I/O or CPU bound (you'd be I/O bound, 99.9% of DB operations are I/O bound operations). Designing your database while avoiding foreign key constraints is awful and proof that premature optimization is the root of all evil. You chose to have inconsistent data under pretense of performance. You never measured what your server *can* do and where it shows signs of slowing down.

Comment: It's clear that you're conscious about what you're doing, but you went about it entirely wrong. Neither will one server be sufficient, nor can you choose to leave features out and ignore consistency because you *think* it contributes to downgraded performance. Even now, when your thing is running - you saw that your load is abysmal.

Comment: I am using foreign keys (see the main post). DB load is really small, performance is very good. My database structure is exactly as it must be for this special application. I don't need timestamps, it's not important when the message arrived, users receiving real-time notifications. They are happy, director is happy, and that's the most important thing.I am employed in this company from apr.1 , the deadline for this app was apr.1  , the other guy was fired bcs was unable to do this app in 3 months, i finished in one week. And the effect-result is perfect, works exactly as it needs to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191526/discussion-between-fehora-and-mjh).

Comment: Scenario: Scenario: You said: "millions of message each hour" I assume 1mio and 10000 users. One user leaves friday 14:00 the office, takes 1 week holiday and is back in office Monday 8:00 (234 hours later). And then his first job is to check 234*1mio/10000 = 2340 messages and then every hour 10 more messages?

Comment: About keep the main table small: You can store the hasheof the users into another table with unique_id and hash as db members. Then you can follow my example with only an interger valuer as user id's. This saves much database memory.